# Is it okay to say "easier" after a verb?

Tags: grammaticality

Is it correct to write 'browse easier' and 'search easier'? When I use my Word grammar check, it doesn't correct them.
Edit: Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned the grammar checker at all. I was looking for verification that the terms above were incorrect. I didn't want to write the following letter until I was sure. After reading your responses here, I sent it. In case you're curious, here it is:
Hello XXXXXXXX,
I am a XXXXXXXX customer who just received your letter promoting the new XXXXXXXX. I'm happy to learn about the changes that are coming. I'm writing because your letter says, "Browse easier" and "search for the shows and movies you love easier". 'Browse more easily' and 'search... more easily' are the way to write those sentences. Perhaps this was an honest mistake because no one who read the letter before it got mass-mailed knew better. In that case, please disregard this e-mail; (you may want to hire a better proofreader.) I'm writing in case XXXXXXXXXX knew it was incorrect but thought its customers needed words to be simplified to the point that they are wrong. We are not stupid. Most of us have an elementary level education, and therefore are familiar with adverbs. Wrong is not more attractive, ie. (XXXXXXincorrectly spelled product nameXXXX), it's just wrong. In the case of customers like me, it actually makes the company sending the letter less attractive. 
Just a thought,
(Signed)

Comment: Please expand your question to include why you think the grammar checker should correct them.

Answer (score 1):

Word grammar check is an extremely unreliable tool, and you should not trust it.

If we can *"breathe easier"* and *"rest easier"*, why can't we *"search easier"*? And how on Earth do you expect Word grammar check to recognize this difference? Do you expect its creators would have given it a list of which verbs can take *"easier"*, and which verbs need *"more easily"*?

To be perfectly grammatical, you should use *"more easily"* with *"browse"* and *"search"*.