# Should "communicate clearer" be "communicate more clearly"

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage

I just saw an ad on Twitter that says: "Communicate clearer by drawing and talking over your images".

It seems to me they aren't communicating very clearly and it would be better to phrase their sentence like this: "Communicate more clearly by drawing and talking over your images".

Can you tell me if I am correct and why I am correct or wrong/mistaken please?

Comment: "Communicate more clearly" is definitely correct but i'll leave it for someone with a more formal knowledge of English to explain why.

Comment: Related - http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2166/more-clear-vs-clearer-when-to-use-more-instead-of-er?rq=1

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This question is completely different from your linked question. It asks about _clearer_ vs _more clearly_, not _clearer_ vs _more clear_.

Comment: @TonyK: One of the answers to the original starts with [The question really ought to be whether to say "clearer" or "more clearly."](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/60414/2637). And clearly there is no such word as ***clearlier***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: But the question itself is not a duplicate. Agreed?

Comment: @TonyK: I think they're essentially about the same thing, and that earlier question has a *lot* of upvotes, so it's the one we should be promoting. If you want to stick to the adjective/adverb distinction it could be closed against [easier, more easily, or easy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232615/) or [Is it okay to say “easier” after a verb?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/264744/) (and doubtless several others), but I'm all for Occam's Razor and "Do not multiply entities unnecessarily".